# How to configure the virtual keyboard in the X server?

Tags: x11, xorg, keyboard, wayland

I am using an embedded Linux for a Toradex system on module. The Linux runs an X server/X11 with xfwm4 window manager. Also, I use a Python desktop app created with the GTK framework.

**How can I configure the X server to open the virtual keyboard when I click, e.g., on a text input control?** I am using the matchbox-keyboard. Currently I open  the keyboard programmatically (manually) from my app.

For instance, in the case of Wayland/Weston there is a weston.ini file where you can specify the path to the virtual keyboard application which it will use. **Is there a similar configuration for X server?**

Any advice is welcome.